# How to convert points to polygons

Tags: qgis

I have a csv file with the positions (x and y) outlining multiple complex polygons. Each point is numbered in a separate field and each polygon is numbered in a separate field. I can load those points into QGIS easily but I cant convert them into distinct polygons. I know there are multiple similar questions but nothing works - convex hull crashes and minimum bounding geometry is too basic. I havent found a distinct package either (im using QGIS 3.14.16).
I dont know. I can I transform a list of points into multiple polygons ? Should be easy but its not.

Comment: Providing a screenshot - or a sample of your data - could increase chances to get an answer that suits your needs.

Comment: Can you share some test data? Convex hull is so simple operation that it is odd if it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import your points using Import -> Delimted text option. Then run **Vector Creation -> Points to path** using your point id field for the "Order field" and your polygon id field as the "Group field". You can check "close path" if you wish. Then run **Vector -> Geometry tools -> Lines to polygons**, which will create a separate polygon from each line. You may, of course, find that some of the generated polygons are invalid geometries with overlapping sides, in which case you can run the **Check Validity tool** in the Processing toolbox.